# Opening Powerpoint Presentation in SlideShow Mode

Tags: vb.net, process, slideshow, powerpoint

I want to open a powerpoint directly in a slideshow mode. The code I am trying to use is this:

```
Process.Start("powerpnt", "/s "str_Presfileopen)
```

'str_Presfileopen is a string containing the path of the file

But this doesn't work. It says that Comma')' or a valid expression continuation expected.

I tried to use the process start info:

```
Dim Presfileopen As New ProcessStartInfo()
Process.Start("powerpnt", "/s " Presfileopen)
```

But this doesn't work as well. Here too it says that Comma')' or a valid expression continuation expected.

What the hell am I doing wrong? 
As a test I wrote in the direct code and this works but I can't do it like this because I need the user to select the file from a list.
The code that works:

```
Process.Start("powerpnt", "/s ""a.pptx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the strings together using the `&` or `+` operator.  You also need to put quotes around it, in case the filename contains spaces:

```
Process.Start("powerpnt", "/s """ & str_PresFileOpen & """")
```

Comment: This works  but once I open a presentation in slideshow mode I cannnot open another without closing the previous one. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module Module1

Sub main()

    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim file As String

    file = "C:\myfile.ppsm" 'example location/file'

    pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = True
    pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(file)

End Sub
End Module
```

Make sure the presentation properties is set to read only.